# Is this string substitution problem decidable?

Tags: undecidability, decision-problem, substrings

We have the following task:

> Take as input a finite set of string pairs.  Each pair represents a substitution.  Replace exactly one instance of the left with the right.   A substitution can only be performed on x if the left is a substring of x.  For example $01\rightarrow 10$ means replace one 01 with 10, and can only be applied if 01 is in the string. The algorithm should decide if for the given set there exists a string such that applying a non - zero number of the substitutions yields the initial string.

I am wondering if this is a decidable task.  It seems like it should be possible to establish an upper bound on the length of the string and number of substitutions, but I haven't been able to.  And from the other end I tried to build a test based on invariants, since invariants can be used to show a lot of sets can't loop.  For example

$$
\{011\rightarrow 101, 101\rightarrow 110\}
$$

Can never produce a loop.  We can show this since each rule decreases the average position of 1s in the string when used.  Thus it can never produce a string with the same average position as the start thus it can never produce the start.

But there are some cases that I can't think of a clever invariant.  For example

$$
\{1001\rightarrow 0110\}
$$

Which clearly can't form a loop, but I can't think of a property which it always increases.

Is this problem decidable?

Comment: Are you familiar with [unrestricted grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar)?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have worked with unrestricted grammars some before but had not made the connection. It would probably be a good idea too rephrase thirds question and have a look.

Comment: In fact this is very easy to answer once rephrased.

Comment: Can you now answer your own question?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I can.  It might be a little while (2 days) before I would write it though.  You did the important insight so if you want the reputation feel free to answer.

Comment: Can you credit the source of all copied material?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @D.W. No material here is copied. I encountered this problem naturally rather than in a corsebook or such.  I used the quote block just as a formatting tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is essentially the same as the question of whether a given string can be generated from a given initial string using a given unrestricted grammar (simple reverse all productions). The latter question is known to be undecidable, since you can simulate the running of a Turing machine using an unrestricted grammar.